# In how many ways can we pick 7 balls out of a bag which contains several red , blue and green balls?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If I approach by assuming I have two sticks and I need to divide 7 balls as several combinations of red , blue and green such that overall I have 7 balls , I am not getting where to put the stick so as to divide it .

I mean I will have to pick some balls from the bag and then put a stick somewhere so as to divide it into 3 partitions but I am not what no of balls to be chosen to select 7 balls .

[image]

Comment: The rules of the game are absolutely unclear.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that all the balls of the same color are placed in the same group?  Is is always the case that red balls are to the left of blue balls and blue balls are to the left of green balls as your picture seems to indicate?  Please clarify the rules.

Comment: No there is no such rule , I just took an example

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_r$ be the number of red balls, $x_g$ and $x_b$ be the number of green and blue balls, respectively. So you want the number of non-negative integer solutions (assuming we are allowed to have **no** balls of a color) to the following:
$$x_r+x_g+x_b=7.$$
This is given by $\binom{7+3-1}{3-1}=\binom{9}{2}=36.$

The idea is to have two $1'$s separate $7$ zeros (where $0'$s represent the balls). Note that the separators will automatically convey the colors chosen so we can treat all $0'$s as being the same. So this becomes a problem of number of binary strings of length $9$ with $2$ ones.

Comment: I am not getting this Statement :.     Note that the separators will automatically convey the colors chosen so we can treat all 0′s as being the same.   When we say separators will automatically convey the Colors chosen , why are we not considering the fact that we will have to even pick balls out of the bag , and we can pick any no of balls , so even need to consider that rght , how do we satisfy this scenario ?

Comment: @RadhaGogia Perhaps you are looking for something that doesn't seem to be clear to me from the question you have posed. Does the order in which the balls are picked matter? Meaning, will *rrgrbbb* be considered different from *rrrgbbb*? If yes, then your statement of the problem needs to be modified. Otherwise, the way I have interpreted would be okay.

Comment: Order doesn't matter , I am not getting just one think why we are not considering the way the balls are picked ? It's becoz we are considering the combination of balls picked rght ?